# Have airlines average fleet age been shrinking?

Tags: safety, airlines, aircraft-age

I had read somewhere that nowadays Average age of Airlines is shrinking. I do not know how much of that is true. I did see this -

https://simpleflying.com/airlines-youngest-fleets/

On the other hand, I read about some of the oldest fleets which have anywhere 15-19 years. There doesn't seem to be any data which gives any correlation if the age of the fleets has been shrinking or growing. I do know that having younger fleets means less-downtime and arguably better safety standards/record. Although, the latter is a mere speculation on my part. Does anybody know of any concrete data which says one or the other.

To make it more simple:

Is Average age of the fleets going up or down around the world?

Comment: For your 2nd question: [Are there statistics showing the relationship between safety and the age of aircraft?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/59449/14897)